# JAVA -How to get string values with loop for i<str.length();

Tags: java

There are 3 input values that are combined to a `string (str)`.  Currently, if the user inputs the values "a", "b", and "c", the program will output "a~b~c~123".  I need each value of `arrASCII` to be multiplied by it's position (in this case, 1, 2, and 3).  So the output should be "a~b~c~149".  I've tried to use `i++` and them `arrASCII.append(((int)c-64)*i)`, to no avail.

Any suggestions to create a loop where the value can be multiplied by `i`?

**EDIT** I have adjusted my code below, but now the input of a, b and c should output a~b~c~246.  The actual output with the below code is a~b~c~000123246 Any ideas why I have the leading 000123???

```
        String str;
    str = gpnText.getText()+wpnText.getText()+wsnText.getText();

 //build ASCII value array   

    StringBuilder arrASCII = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++){
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        if ((int)c >= 65 && (int)c <=90 ){
    arrASCII.append(((int)c -64) * i );
        }
        else if ((int)c >= 97 && (int)c <=122 ){
    arrASCII.append(((int)c -96) * i );
        }
        else if ((int)c >= 48 && (int)c <=57 ){
    arrASCII.append(((int)c -48) * i);
        }
        else 
    arrASCII.append(1 *i);

  //build Calculation Array
    }
  barcodeResult.setText(gpnText.getText()+ "~"+ wpnText.getText()+"~"+wsnText.getText()+"~"+arrASCII.toString());

}
```

Comment: just copy my code. It works like a charm. You must multiply with `(i+1)` not with `i`. And click the check mark at the left of answer.

Comment: And you don't need 2 loop's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length; i++) {
    char c = charArray[i];
    if ((int) c >= 65 && (int) c <= 90) {
        arrASCII.append(((int) c - 64)* (i+1));
    } else if ((int) c >= 97 && (int) c <= 122) {
        arrASCII.append(((int) c - 96)* (i+1));
    } else if ((int) c >= 48 && (int) c <= 57) {
        arrASCII.append(((int) c - 48)* (i+1));
    } else arrASCII.append(1);
}
barcodeResult.setText(gpnText.getText() + "~" + wpnText.getText() +
    "~" + wsnText.getText() + "~" + arrASCII.toString());
```